# Magento 2 : How to overwrite Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement

Tags: quote, shipping-address, override-model

I want to make changes in function estimateByAddressId() which is public method.

I tried following :  app/etc/di.xml also tried in app/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement" type="Vendor\CustomModule\Model\ShippingMethodManagement" />
```

But not succeed. Can anyone please help.

Comment: can you also tell us the use case where are you overriding and what functionality you are trying to achieve, can you try for rest-API area all the checkout API are called via restapi

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps,

1. Create a new module by creating a directory structure in the
   **`app/code`** directory. For example, **`app/code/Vendor/Module`**.
2. Create a **`registration.php`** file in the Vendor/Module directory with
   the following code:

Here is the code

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

3. Create **`module.xml`** file in that path **`etc/module.xml`**

Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Quote" />
        </sequence>  
    </module>
</config>
```

4. Create a **`di.xml`** file in the **`Vendor/Module/etc`** directory with the
   following code:

Here is the code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ShippingMethodManagement" />
</config>
```

5. Create a **`ShippingMethodManagement.php`** file in the
   **`Vendor/Module/Model`** directory with the following code:

Here is the code:-

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class ShippingMethodManagement extends \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement
{
    public function get($cartId)
    {
        // Add your custom logic here
    }
}
```

6. Run the following command to enable the module.

This command

```
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
```

7. Run the following command to upgrade the setup:

This command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

8. Clear the cache and the module will now overwrite the **`Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement`** class with your custom logic

This command

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

---

**Second is the you can override your function using plugin.**

---

1. Create a new module, for example, **`Vendor_ShippingMethod`**
2. Create a new directory Plugin in the **`Vendor_ShippingMethod`** module
3. Create a new file, **`ShippingMethodManagement.php`** in the Plugin
   directory
4. In the **`ShippingMethodManagement.php`** file, define a new class that
   extends from **`Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement`**
5. In the new class, use the around method to overwrite the method you
   want to modify, for example, **`estimateByExtendedAddress`**
6. In the **`around`** method, call the parent method and then add your
   custom code
7. Register the plugin in the **`di.xml`** file of the **`Vendor_ShippingMethod`**
   module
8. Run **`setup:upgrade`** command

You could use this as an example:-

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ShippingMethod\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement;

class ShippingMethodManagement
{
    public function aroundEstimateByExtendedAddress(ShippingMethodManagement $subject, callable $proceed, $cartId, $address)
    {
        // Your custom code
        
        return $proceed($cartId, $address);
    }
}
```

Here is the **`di.xml`** file code:-

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement">
        <plugin name="Vendor_ShippingMethod_Plugin_ShippingMethodManagement" type="Vendor\ShippingMethod\Plugin\ShippingMethodManagement" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

In order to overwrite this class you have to make preference for = `Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagementInterface` . Remember to add dependency of `Quote` module in your `etc/module.xml` file

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Quote" />
</sequence>
```

I don't know what you want to modify in function, but I would recommend to use plugins (before,after or around) instead of overwriting whole class.

Answer (score 0):

1)Create Plugin for it instead of override

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagementInterface">
          <plugin name="allowEmptyQuotes" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Quote\ShippingMethodManagement\Plugin" sortOrder="1"/>
      </type>
</config>
```

2)`app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Quote/ShippingMethodManagement/Plugin.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Quote\ShippingMethodManagement;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;

class Plugin
{
      /**
       * Quote repository.
       *
       * @var QuoteRepository
       */
      protected $quoteRepository;

      /**
       * Shipping method converter
       *
       * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter
       */
      protected $converter;

      /**
       * @param QuoteRepository $quoteRepository Quote repository.
       */
      public function __construct(
          QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
          ShippingMethodConverter $converter
      ) {
          $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
          $this->converter = $converter;
      }

      /**
       * Allow empty quote for calculating the shipping methods / costs
       *
       * Plugin for: @see \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement::estimateByAddress
       *
       * @param $subject
       * @param $result
       */
      public function aroundEstimateByAddress(
          \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement $subject,
          \Closure $proceed,
          $cartId,
          \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\EstimateAddressInterface $address
      ) {
            // Your code
      }
}
```